# C#/ASP web, ASP:Checkbox to do messagebox on client side, if yes run server side code

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I apologize if this has been answered somewhere but I could not find my particular problem's answer.

I have a asp object:

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRemove"  runat="server" Checked='<%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("CommonWord")) %>' OnCheckedChanged
= "OnCheckedChanged_CommonWord" AutoPostBack="true"  />
```

Basically I want to show a message box asking if its ok to remove, if no or cancel is selected, don't do a postback (or don't run any server side code), and if yes then run that function "OnCheckedChanged_CommonWord".

I tried doing a javascript Confirm() call which pops up but if I press yes, the C# server side code does not run ("OnCheckedChanged_CommonWord") the "no" or "cancel" works perfectly as it doesn't do a postback.

P.s. Please no AJAX due to server restrictions for me.

Answer (score 0):

The Checkbox control actually lacks any type of `OnClientCheckChanged` event that can be used to manage if a `PostBack` should occur or not (like `OnClientClick`, etc.) based on a client-side event.

But you should be able to accomplish this using an `onclick` attribute with a function to manage the default `PostBack` by calling it manually :

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkRemove" runat="server"  
       Checked='<%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("CommonWord")) %>' 
       OnCheckedChanged="OnCheckedChanged_CommonWord" 
       AutoPostBack="true"
       onclick='return OnClientCheckChanged("Are you sure you want to do this?",this);' />
<script>
    function OnClientCheckChanged(prompt,source) {
        if (confirm(prompt)){
            __doPostBack("'" + source.id + "'", '');
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

When the CheckBox is actually clicked, it will trigger your `confirm()` prompt and based on the result, it will either trigger an explicit `PostBack` (via the nasty `__doPostBack()` call or it won't do anything.

I'm not a huge fan of the `__doPostBack()` call, but it seems like an appropriate solution here.

Comment: Apologies, I'm not that familiar with Javascript, I added the function you provided, it started complaining about the '' as the second parameter of _doPostBack so I changed it to "".  

Now it is saying the actual function error - Identifier Expected.

Any Ideas?
<script runat="server" type="text/javascript">
   function OnClientCheckChanged(prompt,source) {
        if (confirm(prompt)){
            __doPostBack("'" + source.id + "'", "");
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>